# "To kill someone" vs "To have someone killed"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

In a movie, I’ve heard “**Are you going to have me killed?**”
How’s this different from “**Are you going to kill me?**” Is there a certain rule for that?

If you’re wondering where I heard this, it was *Smallville s01e04 29:05*
The context:

> Have a nice life
>   If you walk out that door, I will make you disappear
>   What are you gonna do? You gonna have me killed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is agency: who is going to do the killing.

> Are you going to kill me?

The person addressed would be the agent.

> Are you going to have me killed?

The person addressed would find other agents to do the killing.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Can I replace “have” with “get”, e.g. “you gonna get me killed?” would it be the same sentence or not?

Comment: @user70960 I think "get" would have a slightly different implication here. When you say "get me killed" it normally implies that the other person puts you in danger of death without implying that the other person intends for you to die. "Get me killed" could be used for engaging in dangerous sports for instance. "have me killed" implies intent and generally suggests directly ordering the killing.